# Confidence intervals for XGRegressor

Tags: python, xgboost

Is there a way to get confidence intervals for XGRegressor predictions? Something like the forest-ci package for scikit random forests? I want a solution for python

Comment: I'm not aware of any package doing that but you could create bootstrap predictions (i.e. calculate many predictions based on slightly different training data) and then calculate confidence intervals from there.

Comment: http://www.real-statistics.com/multiple-regression/confidence-and-prediction-intervals/. hth